# My email for my APPLE ID is deactivated what do I do?

Tags: apple-id

So I've finally remembered my APPLE ID that I used in the beginning to activate my Iphone but I forgot the password which I tried too many times and it disabled. Now my yahoo account I used for it is deactivated due to the fact I haven't logged in 12 months. What do I do?! My phone won't activate unless I use the ID I used in the beginning. I really need help! :/

Answer (score 1):

First, try to reset your Apple ID through https://iforgot.apple.com/password/verify/appleid. And chose the **security questions** instead of Email authentication.

If that doesn't work or you don't remember the answers to your security questions you should try to contact apple support either by phone https://support.apple.com/kb/HT5699 or by visiting an apple store. They'll be able to restore your account for you.